# Segmentation fault(Core Dumped) while trying to open multiple files together to read from them

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

I have three files(written using the python `.tofile` function) with 1024x512 arrays in them with (double)values. I wrote This C program to open the files and load the values to memory array so that I can access them index wise. 
If i try to open just one file and dont try to read the other one, it runs fine and gives me the required values.For example **THIS CODE WORKS LIKE A CHARM**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define xres 1024
#define yres 512
#define xgrid_spacing 0.025                                   //grid spacing along x
#define ygrid_spacing 0.025                                   //grid spacing along y
#define zgrid_spacing 1.0                                     //grid spacing along z

#define xbeg -12.8                                            //X coordinate limits
#define xend 12.8
#define ybeg -6.4                                             //Y coordinate limits
#define yend 6.4
#define zbeg 0.0                                              //Z coordinate limits
#define zend 1.0
void main(){

    const char file0[] = "bx1_1024X512.bin";
    const char file1[] = "bx2_1024X512.bin";
    const char file2[] = "v_crs_b_1024X512.bin";
    FILE *inp0;
    FILE *inp1;
    FILE *inp2;
double xx, yy, zz, xgrid_len, ygrid_len, zgrid_len;
    float xfloat, yfloat, zfloat;
    int xindex, yindex, zindex;

    //index counters
    int iind, jind, ind, jnd;
    //open the file

    double bx_elem, by_elem, bz_elem, v_crs_b_elem;
    inp0 = fopen(file0,"rb");
    inp1 = fopen(file1,"rb");
    inp2 = fopen(file2,"rb");
    //array to store the values
    double bxarray[xres][yres];
    double byarray[xres][yres];
    double minusv_crs_b_array[xres][yres];
    //iterate through the elements and save them to a memory array in C 

    for (iind=0;iind<xres;iind++)
    {
        for (jind=0;jind<yres;jind++)
        {
            fread(&bx_elem, sizeof(double), 1, inp0);
            bxarray[iind][jind]= bx_elem;

        }

    }

    //print the value to check
    printf("%lf\n", bxarray[0][0]);
    //close the file
    fclose(inp0);

}
```

But as soon as i try to read two or more files as shown below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define xres 1024
#define yres 512
#define xgrid_spacing 0.025                                   //grid spacing along x
#define ygrid_spacing 0.025                                   //grid spacing along y
#define zgrid_spacing 1.0                                     //grid spacing along z

#define xbeg -12.8                                            //X coordinate limits
#define xend 12.8
#define ybeg -6.4                                             //Y coordinate limits
#define yend 6.4
#define zbeg 0.0                                              //Z coordinate limits
#define zend 1.0
void main(){

    const char file0[] = "bx1_1024X512.bin";
    const char file1[] = "bx2_1024X512.bin";
    const char file2[] = "v_crs_b_1024X512.bin";
    FILE *inp0;
    FILE *inp1;
    FILE *inp2;
double xx, yy, zz, xgrid_len, ygrid_len, zgrid_len;
    float xfloat, yfloat, zfloat;
    int xindex, yindex, zindex;

    //index counters
    int iind, jind, ind, jnd;
    //open the file

    double bx_elem, by_elem, bz_elem, v_crs_b_elem;
    inp0 = fopen(file0,"rb");
    inp1 = fopen(file1,"rb");
    inp2 = fopen(file2,"rb");
    //array to store the values
    double bxarray[xres][yres];
    double byarray[xres][yres];
    double minusv_crs_b_array[xres][yres];
    //iterate through the elements and save them to a memory array in C 

    for (iind=0;iind<xres;iind++)
    {
        for (jind=0;jind<yres;jind++)
        {
            fread(&bx_elem, sizeof(double), 1, inp0);
            bxarray[iind][jind]= bx_elem;
            fread(&by_elem, sizeof(double), 1, inp1);
            byarray[iind][jind]= by_elem;

        }

    }

    //print the value to check
    printf("%lf\n", bxarray[10][30]);
    //close the file
    fclose(inp0);
    fclose(inp1);

}
```

**I get a segmentation fault(core dumped) error.**
For Clarification: The file exists in the same directory as the code

Comment: 12MB of automatic storage allocation (stack space) usually makes for unhappy processes. Just saying.

Comment: I suspect you're just putting too much stuff on the stack.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz THANKS A TON< YOU ARE RIGHT!!!!! I set ulimit in the terminal to 10 times what it was and now it works like a charmmmm!!!...:D

Comment: The classic [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501112/segmentation-faultcore-dumped-while-trying-to-open-multiple-files-together-to) bug bites again.

Comment: Haha, seems so..!

Comment: OT: regarding: `void main(){`  There are only two valid signatures for `main()` they are: `int main( void )` and `int main(  int argc, char *argv[] )`  Notice that they both have a return type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: OT: regarding: `inp0 = fopen(file0,"rb");
    inp1 = fopen(file1,"rb");
    inp2 = fopen(file2,"rb");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` to output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: strongly suggest moving these statements: `double bxarray[xres][yres];
    double byarray[xres][yres];
    double minusv_crs_b_array[xres][yres];` off the stack and into 'file scope'

Comment: @user3629249 Please elaborate, I would need to do that at some point, but i do not know how to do that.

Comment: move these lines: `double bxarray[xres][yres];
    double byarray[xres][yres];
    double minusv_crs_b_array[xres][yres];` to just before the `main()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the stack size was the problem, setting ulimit -s 102400 (100MB) just to be safe, solved the problem!!